# Display a DIV as over overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm been a back-end developer through and through, and trying to do some UI work, using RoR.

```
I have a list object that I want to display.
Object1
Object2
Object3
Object4
...
```

I have done this bit.

Now when the user clicks on Object1, I want to display the details in the object (something similar to http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/index.htm)

I understand the code in the sample.

You have div that is hidden, on a click you display it. But in my case I have a lot of objects (a couple of hundred), and each object is very large, I don't want to retrieve all the data when page is loaded. So currently when the users clicks on an Object, I simple open a new page, where all the data is detailed display. What I want is to open an overlay like over example, and render the data in it.

I'm not familiar with the lingo for UI development and have a hard type looking for existing implementation of it, before I start coding all my self.

Licensing is an issue for me, so I would like to stick with vanilla jQuery and RoR. instead of using third party libraries with all sort of licensing schemes.

Comment: Please have some sample code, and try it yourself before posting about a specific problem you are having.

Comment: you have to use ajax!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment you can do this by using [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). What it does is, when you click on a link, instead of reloading the whole page, it sends a request to the server asynchronously and returns the response which in turn can be handled in the javascript to update the page.

So in your scenario when a link is clicked, you simple have to send an ajax request to the server, to retrieve the data to be displayed in the overlay box, set the text, and then do the needful to display the overlay box itself.

AJAX can cause little problems when you try to handle it per se. So I suggest using the ajax API of the JQuery library found here : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. This is more easy to use and also cross browser compatible.

for a div like this :

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
<button id="load">Load Box</button>
```

you can use somehing like this :

```
$("#load").click(function(){
  //ajax request
  $.ajax({
    url: "your/web/service.aspx",
    cache: false
  })
  .done(function(response_text){
     //setting the response got to the overlay box
     //this can be a plain text or html or json. 
     //you need to set the box appropriately.  
     $("#overlay").text(response_text);
     //then do the needful to display overlay box
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment by Lakshmi you should load and display the overly data using an Ajax method. Your Ajax response should fill a hidden element with the objects details and then trigger the overly to show.